# How to sort the result based on a certain column when using GROUP BY in sql statement

Tags: mysql

I am new to this, so please be patient...

1. I have a table "tFruit".
2. The fields inside tFruit are "ID", "Buyer", "Seller", "Time", and "FruitName".
3. "ID" is the key field, the other 4 fiends has non-unique data.

When I use this SQL statement I will get all sellers sorted by Time. But an individual seller appears multiple times because they sold fruits not only once.

```
SELECT Seller 
FROM tFruit 
WHERE Buyer = 'email@address.com' 
ORDER BY Time DESC
```

What I want is to get the list of seller, non-duplicate, sorted by Time. Thus I use this statement:

```
SELECT Seller 
FROM tFruit 
WHERE Buyer = 'email@address.com' 
GROUP BY Seller 
ORDER BY Time DESC
```

Now there is no duplicate Seller, but they are not sorted by Time.

Any ideas how to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the `Time` field to your `select` list, as in:

```
SELECT Seller, Max(Time) AS MostRecentTime 
FROM tFruit 
WHERE Buyer = 'email@address.com' 
GROUP BY Seller 
ORDER BY Max(Time) DESC;
```

`Max(Time) as MostRecentTime` will display the most recent `Time` for the given `Seller`.  You don't really need this in the `SELECT` clause, you really only need `MAX(Time)` in the `ORDER BY` clause.  I've added it to the `SELECT` clause so you can see the results are sorted by Time in descending order.

Comment: Also if you put in the `SELECT` list, you can use `ORDER BY MostRecentTime DESC`

Comment: Note side some extra thoery why... GROUP BY will always fetch the first FIFO record that matches the GROUP BY column(s). 
And only the column Seller is correct, the column  Time is "random" matched.

ORDER BY wont work because it will run after the GROUP BY thats why you cant sort un the Time column like that, GROUP BY is sometimes an evil thing in MySQL where mistakes are very easy to make

Comment: I admit I didn't see the [tag:mysql] tag.